# jQuery selector on variable containing HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select all the anchors contained in a variable that is html as below my code:

```
var deposti_row = "
<a data-country='uk' data-currency='eur' data-matching='country-currency'> AA </a>
<a data-country='uk' data-currency='eur' data-matching='country'> BB </a>
<a data-country='uk' data-currency='eur' data-matching='none'> CC </a>
"

$("a['data-matching']",$(deposit_row)).each( function(){
console.log(this);
});
```

But i get the error Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a['data-matching'] . Any help please ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/6pa6fmqf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. Anyway, what you really want is to filter matched set:

```
$(deposit_row).filter('a[data-matching]').each(...)
```

And your string syntax is wrong too regarding handling mutliple lines.
And `deposti_row` is not the same as `deposit_row`.

That makes many things wrong is so few posted code...

Comment: Also, need to take care of multi-line text variable

Comment: @Satpal Ya good point. Indeed, many things wrong in OP posted code

Comment: @MrCode Sorry but which root element are you talking about? OP wants to filter out selection i guess

Answer (score 1):

Heres another way:-

1. create your multiline string with `\`.
2. As theres no root, check with `has` inside your each.

```js
var deposit_row = "\
<a data-country='uk' data-currency='eur' data-matching='country-currency'> AA </a>\
<a data-country='uk' data-currency='eur' data-matching='country'> BB </a>\
<a data-country='uk' data-currency='eur' data-matching='none'> CC </a>\
";

$(deposit_row).each(function() {
  if ($(this).has('[data-matching]'))
    console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I really don't think it is what OP is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove single quotes from the attribute selector, then it should work as long anchor tag `a` has a parent element.

You need to wrap them in a `div` to treat them as descendants

```
deposit_row = $(deposit_row).wrap("<div></div>").html();

$("a[data-matching]",$(deposit_row)).each( function(){
   console.log(this);
});
```

Also try this if `a['data-matching']` is the child of a root node

```
$(deposit_row).find("a['data-matching']").each(function(){
});
```

But since `a` is the root node here

```
$(deposit_row).children("a['data-matching']").each(function(){
});
```

Comment: @RayonDabre i think he has given quotes to the attribute name

Comment: @Guru, Second argument in `$` will act as parent of the selector...Much like `.find()`.. Wrapping all `a` elements in any parent will help!